# UL height not expanding all the way down with floating LI

Tags: css, css-float, html-lists

Hi,

I got this code:

```
  <ul>
   <li>some list</li>
   <li>some list</li>
   <li>some list</li>
   <li>some list</li>
   <li>some list</li>
   <li>some list</li>
  </ul>
```

and my css:

```
ul {
background-color: #EDEADF;
height: 30px;
}

li {float: left;}
```

on a PC screen this looks fine. The problem comes when you see it on a mobile because the LI elements go vertical instead of horizontal. Im okay with that, but what I dont like is that the UL stays at the same height and since it has a background it looks weird. It should expand automatically and reach the bottom to cover until the very last LI. How can i achieve that effect?

Thank you.

Comment: Consult this article to see options for fixing this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Comment: Wow, it works like a charm. I dont know how but it does. Thank you.